# Can't open a page's advanced settings in browser

Tags: django, django-cms

So I have a Django CMS installation, and I did some configurations and I can't figure out the problem.

```
AttributeError at /admin/cms/page/5/advanced-settings/
attribute app_title not found

Error during template rendering
In template /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/includes/fieldset.html error at line 19
```

Code:

```
17        <div class="readonly">{{ field.contents }}</div>
18    {% else %}      
19        {{ field.field }}
20    {% endif %}
```

Sorry I can't copy paste or take screenshot.

Comment: I have the same issue. In my setup I have python 3.7 on the development computer and 3.5 on the production server, Django CMS 3.5.3, same problem with 3.6 and Django 1.11.21. On the development machine, rendering od the advanced settings is aborted, on the production server I can open the advanced settings at least sometimes, but they are incomplete, ending with the redirection field, but I can’t configure app hooks. If the issue occurs, depends on the user account: With my admin account I have this problem, with a test account and another colleague’s account the advanced settings do open.

Comment: Hey have you found solution of this issue because currently I am also getting same problem . thanks.

Comment: @Moon any solution?

Comment: @sodimel use Wagtail :)

Comment: @alias51 Oh thanks for the reminder! I actually solved this problem yesterday. It was related to a djangocms-blog config instance that had falsy values after an update of the settings (default language, language list...). I removed/recreated the settings, and all is now working as expected :)

Comment: Also I'm using djangocms-blog on a multisite setup, and I forgot to add `BLOG_MULTISITE = True` in the settings of one of the sites.